# jquery Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #privacy.t.do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project with the following the script. It was working fine with jquery-1.7.2.js. Once upgraded to jquery-1.10.2.js, the error below started showing in chrome:

**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #privacy.t.do?...**

Could anyone help me with this please. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
 var staticSnippet  = ($('#'+action).length > 0),
 snipholderid  = 'snipholder',
 snipidref    = '#'+snipholderid;

 if(staticSnippet) {
   // Check the content to see if there's a header.  Need
   // to check this before we display the dialog box.
   if($('#'+action).find('h2.diagheader').length > 0) {
     _diagProps.title = $('#'+action).find('h2.diagheader>span').html();
   }
 }
```

Comment: What's the value of `action`? How does your DOM look like?

Comment: The value of myh action is an url: "#privacy.t.do?ticket=1382626878090AD18856B891DCD799D9FE92E6A68F8B0214BEB63" that is being returned by java in the back-end. And this how my DOM looks like: "<ul class="footerlinks adaTabFooterLinks">
        <li><a href="#" id="privacydisc" aria-haspopup="true">Privacy</a> <span aria-hidden="true">|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="securitydisc" aria-haspopup="true">Security</a> <span aria-hidden="true">|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="legaldisc" aria-haspopup="true">Legal Disclosures</a></li>
      </ul>

Comment: That doesn't look much like an url. Is it the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), does it contain a query part? Very weird. At least, it's definitely invalid as a DOM selector (and you don't need to prepend it with `#` if it already starts with one).